# Receiving error "Connection Refused" on Chrome sign in

Tags: google-chrome, login

I have a user on a new laptop who is trying to sign into Chrome. However when trying to sign in with a Virgin media account the login page instantly goes to a "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" page, specifically via http://identity2.virginmedia.com.

I have confirmed that sign in on the Virgin media website works normally with http://identity.virginmedia.com and have successfully pinged http://identity2.virginmedia.com

Comment: Sounds like a configuration problem on the user's end most likely dealing with the system's certificate store.

Comment: One way to verify that is indeed the problem is to use Firefox since it uses an entirely separate certificate store from Chrome or IE.

Comment: Seems to be a smeg up of Virgin's end. identity.virginmedia works fine but identity2.virginmedia looks to be down and Chrome is trying to use that to authenticate